# Синонимизировать [аннотации] и [annotations]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Хорошо бы [annotations](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/annotations) сделать синонимом для [аннотации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8).

[Проголосуйте за синоним на странице метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/synonyms#).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Коли имеете в виду вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То могу прямо сейчас сделать)

Comment: Не уверен, что объединение - это тоже самое, что синоним.

Comment: @Suvitruf, о, нашёл как утвердить предложенный синоним. Готово)

Comment: Ага, благодарю ^_^

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я думал, там старая троица должна была вам организовать КМБ, а то понаворотите тут ;)

Comment: @alexolut, всё так и было) Просто не сразу вспомнил как там ещё можно)

Comment: _"Подождите, не объединяйте"_ - надпись несколько странно выглядит на кнопке...

Comment: @mymedia, потому я и задумался, стоит ли сразу жать на объединение)